# Handle Redirect after Form submission in requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the content from a website : URL1 : http://jamabandi.nic.in/land records/querylink.aspx

So, when you submit the form, it redirects to another page : URL2 : http://jamabandi.nic.in/land%20records/owner.aspx

I am trying to scrape the content after the form submission. I notice that, when the form is submitted, URL1 throws a 302 error and redirects to URL2.

However, when I do the form submission through Python requests, I get status code as 200. Here is the code snippet i am using :

```
    postFields = hidden_fields
    postFields['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddldname'] = district
    postFields['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddltname'] = tehsil
    postFields['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlvname'] = village
    postFields['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button1'] = 'Submit'

    header = {}
    url = 'http://jamabandi.nic.in/land%20records/querylink.aspx'
    page = requests.post(url, data=postFields, headers=header, timeout=10, allow_redirects=True)
    print page.status_code  // 200
```

Any idea what is missing here ?

Comment: Hey Kiran, did my answer help you?

Comment: Hello @waqasgard, I am extremely it was not useful. However, i did find a solution . Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Okay @Kiran. What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

After a little inspection this is what I think might be going on.

When you submit the form on your website the redirection happens hence `302`

When you submit it through `requests` the redirection does not happen but nothing fails as such hence `200`.

I can't tell you what's exactly going on coz I can't see the `APIs`. This is my best guess.